# Aligning molecule names

Tags: chemfig

I'm writing a reaction but the names of the D-Glucose and D-Mannose are not aligned with the name of the D-Fructose.
Here's what I have. I tried to use `\chemnameinit{}` but it simply didn't work :(

Also, I'd like to put a title like a table or image but I don't know how.

```
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\definesubmol{x}{(-[4]H)(-[0]OH)}
\definesubmol{y}{(-[0]H)(-[4]HO)}

\begin{center}
\schemestart
    \chemname{\chemfig{[2]CH_2 \cdot OH-!x-!x-!y-!x-(-[3]H)=[1]O}}{D-Glucosa}
    \arrow{<=>[Base][]}
    \chemname{\chemfig{[2]CH_2 \cdot OH-!x-!x-!y-(=[0]O)-CH_2 \cdot OH}}{D-Fructosa}
    \arrow{<=>[Base][]}
    \chemname{\chemfig{[2]CH_2 \cdot OH-!x-!x-!y-!y-(-[3]H)=[1]O}}{D-Manosa}
\schemestop
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`chemfig` places the molecules in a `bounding box` defined by `TikZ`. I haven't found how to modify or act on this `bounding box`. So, I propose a quick hack by adding `35 pt` to the default size of the text of the `\chemname[35pt]` command.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\definesubmol{x}{(-[4]H)(-[0]OH)}
\definesubmol{y}{(-[0]H)(-[4]HO)}

\begin{center}

\schemestart
    \chemname{\chemfig{[2]CH_2 \cdot OH-!x-!x-!y-!x-(-[3]H)=[1]O}}{D-Glucosa}
    \arrow{<=>[Base][]}
    \chemname[35pt]{\chemfig{[2]CH_2 \cdot OH-!x-!x-!y-(=[0]O)-CH_2 \cdot OH}}{D-Fructosa}
    \arrow{<=>[Base][]}
    \chemname{\chemfig{[2]CH_2 \cdot OH-!x-!x-!y-!y-(-[3]H)=[1]O}}{D-Manosa}
\schemestop

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked pretty well.

Answer (score 5):

A solution with `vphantom`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\definesubmol{x}{(-[4]H)(-[0]OH)}
\definesubmol{y}{(-[0]H)(-[4]HO)}

\begin{center}

\schemestart
    \chemname{\chemfig{ [2]CH_2 \cdot OH-!x-!x-!y-!x-(-[3]H)=[1]O}}{D-Glucosa}
    \arrow{<=>[Base][]}
    \chemname{\vphantom{\chemfig{[2]CH_2 \cdot OH-!x-!x-!y-!x-(-[3]H)=[1]O}}
        \chemfig{[2]CH_2 \cdot OH-!x-!x-!y-(=[0]O)-CH_2 \cdot OH}}{D-Fructosa}
    \arrow{<=>[Base][]}
    \chemname{\chemfig{[2]CH_2 \cdot OH-!x-!x-!y-!y-(-[3]H)=[1]O}}{D-Manosa}
\schemestop

\end{center}

\end{document}
```